# Is it necessary to take the inferior limit of this sequence of integrals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A $ is a measurable set, and $\{h _n \} $ is a sequence of nonnegative simple functions such that $h _n \uparrow \chi _A $, where $\chi _A $ is the charachteristic function.

**I wonder why in proving that $\int h _n d \mu \uparrow \mu (A) $, I need to show that $\lim \inf \int h _n d \mu \ge \mu(A )$, and  not just $\lim \int h _n d \mu \ge \mu(A )$. What is the difference?**

---

Trivially I have that $\lim \int h_n d \mu \le \mu (A) $ , since the integral is monotone. And since $h _n $ is an increasing sequence $\int h _n d \mu$, also is increasing.

For the opposite inequality,
I can define sets $A _n= \{s \in A : h _n (s ) > 1 - \epsilon \} $

And I would believe that $\lim \int _{A _n } h _n d \mu \ge (1-\epsilon )\lim \mu(A _n) \to (1-\epsilon )\mu (A) $

Am I missing something? Do I have to thake the inferior limit in this last expression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why $\mu(A_n) \to \mu(A)$?

Comment: This would folllow since $A _n $ is an increasing sequence of sets, and $\mu $ is countably additive, hence "continuous " under a monotone sequence.

Comment: Yeah, I think your proof is good. Since $\int h_n d\mu$(or $\int_{A_n} h_n d\mu$) is an increasing sequence, there is no difference in taking $\lim$ or $\liminf$. By the way, do you know [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)? You can also use this to prove your result

Comment: No, the book I'm currently reading (Williams Probability with martingales) uses monotone convergence theorem, for which this lemma is neadedm, to prove the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Ok, then let's follow the logic order :)